# Data code not working? in sms api

Tags: php, sms

```
<?php
 $url = "https://semysms.net/api/3/sms.php"; //Url address for sending SMS
 $phone = '+123456'; // Phone number
 $msg = 'CHECK TEST';  // Message
 $device = '00000';  //  Device code
 $token = '0c3d05001be0e1a65766d205ed262597';  //  Your token (secret)

 $data = array(
        "phone" => $phone,
        "msg" => $msg,
        "device" => $device,
        "token" => $token
    );

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);     
    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);


?>
```

I am trying to add this code `<?=$data->Phone;?>` to show a number on above in above given SMS api but it seems like its not working. This code shows a phone number of buyers on my website. So i thought it will work need help. I want to show phone numbers in above API.

Comment: What is the curl response ($output) you are receiving ??